# Odd behaviour with Netbeans 18 and Java

Tags: java, netbeans

I just installed NetBeans 18.
When I open it and select "new Project" and fill in the questions and say finish it creates a java file containing a "hello world" main function.

I am trying to create new project and do not understand WHY NB does this or how to get rid of it.

Comment: That isn't _"odd behavior"_; it is the default and expected behavior, regardless of which build tool you use (Maven/Ant/Gradle). NetBeans will create a working project that will display _"Hello World!"_ when you run it. This is not new, because NetBeans has always done this. And creating a trivial project, building it and running it is a good way of verifying that your IDE is installed correctly. What is your actual concern? All you need to do is remove one line in `main()` and add your own code. Can you clarify what you want or expect NetBeans to do instead?

Comment: Thank you. I have not used Netbeans before and was surprised and thought I had done something in error.